# Problem with the Loop - want to limit the access to three free articles

Tags: plugins, loop, limit, user-access

What I'm trying to do:
If anyone who is not logged in, reads an article, I will increase a session var by one. Save that article ID via global $post and save the `$post->ID` to an array. After 3 articles I will show a login or register form. So I want to limit the free access to the articles to three. The 3 already watched articles should be able to be read anyway.

The main part of the code:

```
    function cta_main($content){   
   global $post;
   if(!is_user_logged_in()){
    if(!isset($_SESSION['last_posts'])){
      $_SESSION['last_posts']=array();
      $_SESSION['count']=1;
      $_SESSION['restriction']=false;
    }
    echo "POST_SIZE: ".sizeOf($post);
   echo "<br />Count: ".$_SESSION['count'];
    if(is_singular() && !$_SESSION['restriction'] && is_main_query()){
      if(!cta_isInFreeToWatch()){
      //array_push($_SESSION['last_posts'],$post->post_title);
          $_SESSION['count']++;
          $_SESSION['last_posts'][]=$post->ID;

      }     
      if(sizeOf($_SESSION['last_posts'])>=3)
      $_SESSION['restriction']=true;
    }  
  }  
  echo "<br /> verbot: ".$_SESSION['restriction'];
  echo "<br /> anzahl: ".sizeOf($_SESSION['last_posts']);
  echo "<br /> aktuell: ".$post->ID;
  echo "<br />";
  print_r($_SESSION['last_posts']);  
      if($_SESSION['restriction'])
          return  cta_get_the_restricted_area_message();

      if(!$_SESSION['restriction'] || cta_isInFreeToWatch())
        return $content;
 }
```

**The Problem:**
First article-> Everything is fine. So the article id is in the array.
Second article-> now it's weird, after loading the page the array has 3 or more ids in it. I don't understand why because I ask for `is_single()` but it runs multiple times. With every click it adds multiple ids to the array. **Why?**
I'm sure it's something about the loop but I can't find a solution for that. I think before loading the entire page the function is called multiple times. 
(`add_filter('the_content','cta_main');` that's when the function is called).

Comment: browser pre-fetch?

Comment: if so, how can i prevent that.

or how can i find out?